# Best statistical test for a particular biological experiment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I have run an experiment in which I measure the expression of a particular gene under three different medium conditions (neutral,ATPlo,ATPhi). We took samples who have two different genotypes for a particular SNP (AA,AG).
What I would like to show is that for samples with the AA genotypes the medium has an effect on the expression of the gene while for samples with the AG genotype there is no effect.
Which is the best test to prove this?
If I do an Anova for samples with genotype AA considering the medium as a factor I get a significant pvalue. If I do Anova for samples with genotype AG the pvalue is not significant. If I do a two-way Anova(medium/genotype) with interaction effects the genotype is the only variable that comes up significant.
What can I conclude about my hypothesis? Are there other tests which are more appropriate?

Comment: I forgot to mention that mediums are applied to cells coming from the same sample (so for every sample we have three measurements)

Comment: Is the outcome whether or not the gene is expressed? Does the medium have an effect in the sense that the probability of expression differ between the two genotypes?

Comment: what kind of variable is expression of gene? (binary? presence/absence or continuous?)- as stated by @MichaelChernick this is important. Regarding your research question, i think you are looking for an interaction effect between genotype and medium. Do not test the genotypes separately since your hypothesis rely on factorial design. How many replicates do you have? Three measurements is TOO LOW for testing hypothesis, this is one of the reasons of your failure with testing. Try to get more data

Comment: My point was that if expression of gene is binary logistic regression might be a better model.

Comment: Gene expression is a continuous variable. For each combination genotype/medium I have 3 samples. I plan to get more data but only if at least there is a trend for significance (experiments are very expensive and you need to convince people to give you blood). The test I tried yesterday is two-way anova where Medium is a within-subject factor and genotype is a between-subject factor...in that case the pvalue for interaction is 0.054, that gives me some hope that it will get significant when I get more samples

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have sufficient biological and technical replicates that you have not mentioned, a regression analysis should be sufficient. If you have a one-off experiment you are unlikely to get any robust results due to the natural variance associated with this type of experiment.

There are 2 ways I would go about this, given enough statistical power. The second option will require a larger sample size, but will give 'better' results (the exact size will be specific to your experiment and methods).

#### Option 1: Stratified Linear Regression

Perform a stratified analysis - first analyze the cells with genotype AA, then with genotype AG, with expression of your gene as the outcome and the type of media as a factor variable. In this way you can see the effect of the 2 ATP media compared to the 'neutral' media, assuming that the neutral media is coded as the bottom, or lowest, category.

By then comparing the associations between the expression and media in the separate genotypes you could determine if the expression was more associated with the media type in the AA or AG cells.

#### Option 2: Instrumental Variable Analysis

Again using a linear regression, you can determine the variance in the gene expression data that is determined by the genotype. To do this simply use a linear regression with the expression as the outcome, and the genotype as the only independent variable. Extracting the 'fitted values' from the model gives the predicted expression using only the genotype.

This variable you have now extracted can be used as the new outcome in a linear model, again with the media-type as an explanatory factor variable. This model shows you the association between each ATP media-type (compared to the neutral media) and the expression variance caused by the genotype. If this association is significant, there is a causal association between the genotype and the expression, in the context of the different media.